# How we can compare if two numbers are in any range in MFC(VC++)?

Tags: visual-c++, mfc

How we can compare if two numbers are in any range in MFC(VC++)?
I want to compare if 172 and 185 lies in range 128-191 ?
How i can do this in VC++?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually you just compare the input to the two ends of the range. `if (lower < x && x < upper) ...`